# How does Stackoverflow do the "You earned a new badge" window?

Tags: javascript, ajax, notifications

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Notify panel similar to stackoverflow’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366857/notify-panel-similar-to-stackoverflows)
>   [How to show popup message like in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow)

How does Stackoverflow do the "You earned a new badge" window?  (the orange one that pops up at the top of the screen, I believe its the one that shows you the FAQ when your not logged in).

Anyone have a code sample to do this? (with the button to close the window also?)

Comment: Why don't you take a look at their source code? ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow/659243#659243

Comment: Because you won't see it in the source code and will have to follow some links to external scripts/CSS files.

Comment: the server side code is far more interesting in this case :)

Comment: look at some CSS libraries like Dojo etc which have these effects.

Answer (score 5):

**This is a very simple excersise in HTML, CSS, and DOM manipulation.**  Take a look at http://jquery.com to add effects, etc...

Using these styles in your css:

```
#banner
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #aaf;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: .5em;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

And this HTML on yourpage:

```
<div id="banner">
    Your text here
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('banner').style.display = 'none'; return false;">close</a>
</div>
```

Should do the trick.  Play with the styles, etc... to make it look nice.