# jQuery slider from top like the one on Stackoverflow

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a similar slider as SO are using for when a user get's a badge.

Can anyone show me an example please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the same as [Notify panel similar to stackoverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366857/notify-panel-similar-to-stackoverflows) and also similar to [How to show popup message like in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow/659243#659243)

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at jQuery UI's animate (http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/)