# How To: Stackoverflow / Twitter JS dialogue box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a text-bar above the website like [Twitter or SO does.](http://techdows.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/older-verison-of-twitter.png) Any advice on how to build this would be great. I do not know what you call this feature, but maybe there is a jQuery plugin to do it?

The functionality I'm thinking of is "message" [x] to close the alert.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: very cruel. have you not seen the same at Stack Overflow. that too with a close button?

Comment: lol sorry forgot about that one...but yes you are right

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show popup message like in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to unnecessarily use jQuery Plugins. Just put the HTML you wanna display as a panel.
This is the code for Stack Overflow notifier

The HTML

```
<div id="notify-container">
    <div id="notify--1" style="">
        <span class="notify-close"><a title="dismiss this notification" onclick="$('#notify-container').slideUp();">×</a></span>
        <span class="notify-text">
            Welcome to Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers — check out the <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>!
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
 #notify-container {
    color: #735005;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#notify-container div {
    background-color: #F4A83D;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D6800C;
    padding: 7px 0;
}
#notify-container span.notify-close {
    background-color: #FAD163;
    border: 2px solid #735005;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#notify-container a {
    color: #735005;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#notify-container span.notify-close a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

If you wanna see it in action, [view the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/PwfVh/)

Also, if you are particular about the close button, then you might need some ajax calls that stops showing the notifier at a page refresh or like wise events when the user has closed the notifier by clicking on x mark. SO does it by calling

```
StackExchange.notify.closeFirstTime()
```

Also worthwhile to read are

1. [How to show popup message like in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow/659243#659243)
2. [Notify panel similar to stackoverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366857/notify-panel-similar-to-stackoverflows)

P.S: To close the fiddle, I have used [jQuery slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/). If you are using pure javascript feel free to use

```
document.getElementById('notify-container').style.display ='none';
```

Comment: I have made some change in it using `animate` check here - http://jsfiddle.net/PwfVh/1/

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of the Twitter notification bar using jQuery is available here:
http://pandiyachendur.blogspot.com/2010/07/twitter-like-notification-bar-in-jquery.html

See it in action here: http://jsbin.com/ifidu4/3/edit